# Colour and transparency in plotly plot based on two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I'm making a stacked+grouped bar chart in plotly. I have a dict of colours for each category, but I would like each of the groups to have a different transparency to distinguish them.

The data looks like this:

```
      year    subplot  plot_label   value
0     2019  Projected  Category 1   3.1
1     2020  Projected  Category 1   3.0
2     2021  Projected  Category 1   2.8
3     2019  Projected  Category 2   3.1
4     2020  Projected  Category 2   3.0
5     2021  Projected  Category 2   2.8
6     2019     Actual  Category 1   3.1
7     2020     Actual  Category 1   3.0
8     2021     Actual  Category 1   2.8
9     2019     Actual  Category 2   3.1
10    2020     Actual  Category 2   3.0
11    2021     Actual  Category 2   2.8
```

And the code for plotting:

```
colour_dict = {'Category 1': '#123', 'Category 2': '#456'}

fig = px.bar(df, x='subplot', y='value', facet_col='year', color='plot_label',
             facet_col_spacing=0.01, color_discrete_map=colour_dict)
```

At the moment `Projected` and `Actual` bars have the same colour scheme based on the `plot_label` categories, but I want to add change the alpha of one of them to distinguish the side-by-side bars. Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

Since it is not possible to set individual transparency in express, it must be handled by a graph object. I have set up a subplot based on the data extracted for each category unit of the data frame. I also set the transparency to the category value. The colors of the markers were changed to distinguish the transparency. The legend is now a single legend, since it is duplicated due to the fact that the graph was created by rows of data. The rest of the data is now consistent with the way it looks in express.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

#colour_dict = {'Category 1': '#123', 'Category 2': '#456'}
colour_dict = {'Category 1': '#808080', 'Category 2': '#dc143c'}

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3, subplot_titles=[f'year={str(y)}' for y in [2019,2020,2021]])

for i,y in enumerate(df['year'].unique()):
    dfy = df.query('year == @y')
    for c in dfy['plot_label'].unique():
        dfc = dfy.query('plot_label == @c')
        for s in dfc['subplot'].unique():
            dfs = dfc.query('subplot == @s')
            opacity = 0.5 if dfs['subplot'].values[0] == 'Actual' else 1.0
            color = colour_dict['Category 2'] if dfs['plot_label'].values[0] == 'Category 2' else colour_dict['Category 1'] 
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                x=dfs['subplot'],
                y=dfs['value'],
                marker=dict(color=color,
                           opacity=opacity
                          ),
                legendgroup=dfs['plot_label'].values[0],
                legendgrouptitle_text='Category',
                name=c,
            ), row=1, col=i+1)

# Remove duplicate legends
names = set()
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace:
        trace.update(showlegend=False)
        if (trace.name in names) else names.add(trace.name))

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.update_layout(xaxis2_title='subplot', yaxis_title='value')
fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder="normal")

fig.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I found that the interactive legend didn't work properly. When I selec "Category 1" to show or hide it, it only applies to the first subplot. With the express method it works across all subplots.

Comment: I did not check the legend to see how it worked. Grouping the legend would be equivalent to express.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer after some experimentation. I decided to make a new combination in the dataframe which is a melding of `subplot` and `plot_label`, and then make a new colour definition dict which adds an opacity to the Projected colours.

```
df['label_meld'] = df['subplot'] + ' ' + df['plot_label']
```

df:

```
      year    subplot  plot_label   value  label_meld
0     2019  Projected  Category 1   3.1    Projected Category 1
1     2020  Projected  Category 1   3.0    Projected Category 1
...
8     2021     Actual  Category 1   2.8       Actual Category 2
9     2019     Actual  Category 2   3.1       Actual Category 2
```

then:

```
colours = list(colour_dict.values)
colours = [plotly.colors.hex_to_rgb(i) for i in colours]
opacity = 0.7

opac_colours = [(j[0], j[1], j[2], opacity) for j in colours]
colours = [(j[0], j[1], j[2], 1.0) for j in colours]
colours = colours + opac_colours

colours = ['rgba(' + str(j[0]) + ', ' + str(j[1]) + ', ' + str(j[2]) + ', ' + str(j[3]) + ')' for j in colours]

colour_names = list(colour_dict.keys)
a = ['Actual ' + i for i in colour_names]
b = ['Projected ' + i for i in colour_names]
colour_names = a + b

colour_dict = {}
for i, j in zip(colours, colour_names):
     colour_dict[j] = i

fig = px.bar(df, x='subplot', y='value', facet_col='year',
             color='label_meld', facet_col_spacing=0.01, 
             color_discrete_map=colour_dict)
```

Unfortunately this method doubles every entry in the legend (i.e. there's an "Actual Category 1" entry and a "Projected Category 1" entry)